# Llenar un Arraylist Double con String

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo `ArrayList<Double> numeros= new ArrayList<>();`
y lo quiero llenar con un `String` por ejemplo: "3,6,3,6,3", es posible?

Comment: SI es posible, pero revisa por favor [ask].y modifica tu pregunta por favor, agrega lo que has intentado, saludos.

Comment: Es esto Java? por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/263452/edit) agregando un poco más de información..

Comment: @Elenasys, no entiendo el por que de  los votos negativos a la respuesta que propuse,  necesito saber el por qué, así puedo generar una respuesta más acorde.

Comment: @Ikabod no podemos saber quien realizó los votos, supongo que fue debido a que se contesto una pregunta que no tiene un formato correcto y que al final solo sería de utilidad a quien pregunta pero no para la comunidad :(.

Answer (score -1):

Algo asi podría ser con streams.

```
String numeros = "3,6,3,6,3";
List<Double> lista = Arrays.stream(numeros.split(",")).map(Double::parseDouble).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Por favor explica cómo y por qué funciona tu respuesta para que programadores menos experimentados puedan aprovecharla.

Answer (score -3):

Con la instrucción `Double.parseDouble` puedes convertir de `String` a `Double` te dejo el siguiente ejemplo para que pruebes, y con el método Split de la clase String puedes separar tu String por cada `,`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String number = "3,6,3,6,3";
        String[] arrOfStr = number.split(","); //con este metodo separas x coma

        ArrayList dou = new ArrayList();
        for(String a : arrOfStr){
           dou.add(Double.parseDouble(a));
           System.out.println(a);
        } 

     }
}
```

La salida del código es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero si quiero que cada numero sea un objeto?

Comment: de que manera ?? , ejemplificame.

Comment: ok ya entendí, cada coma del String es un numero aparte. con el metodo split podrias separar la cadena y agregarlo al ArrayList() , modifique la respuesta.

Comment: @Carlos puedes ver este ejemplo en el siguiente enlace http://tpcg.io/ty4sat